# How to run jar file in Azure Data Factory (ADF)

Tags: azure-data-factory

I Have a Jar file. that takes arguments and perform certain actions.

EX:

```
java -jar MyJavaEx.jar dev
```

this jar file will execute some logic inside it and then prints some log.

I want run this job daily using ADF trigger. how to do this?

***if this is not possible what's the best alternative approach.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a lightweight, serverless way to run your Java app, I'd consider [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/function).

You might find this document helpful:

[Azure Functions Java developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java)